# how to stem large csv file using PorterStemmer in Python?

Tags: python, csv, porter-stemmer, stem

I am recently doing project in nlp using python. Where I need to preprocess a csv file which contains text with many row and column. I could became able to stem only simple sentence only. And couldn't able to stem whole csv file at once. How can I do that?

Comment: Loop over all sentences and analyze each one, then recreate your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to read the entire CSV file and stem each cell. The [Python `csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) will allow you to read the CSV file. You'll probably want to use `csv.reader()` or `csv.DictReader()`. The first will allow you to loop through the rows of the CSV and read them individually; the second will automatically put the data from the CSV into a Python [dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). Either would be a good option for your task.

Once you have read in the CSV, you will need to stem the words you have read in. You might use the [`nltk` library](http://www.nltk.org/), which you might need to install, if you have not already done that. [Here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html) is a resource about stemming with `nltk`.